# Ubuntu resize just the Launcher

Tags: unity, 14.04

In older versions of Ubuntu you used to be able to scale down the size of the Launcher, but now I have installed Ubuntu 14.04, and that option in the GUI was changed. It now scales down/up every element of the interface. Is there any way I could maybe edit some file or something, in order to only reduce the size of the Launcher?